# It said error, cannot find symbol. symbol: variable scanner location: class CoffeeBot

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Here is my code[*enter image description here*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQCl9.png)

So I just want to ask user a yes or no and then response to their answer(y/n)
Here is actually my whole code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CoffeeBot {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        if ((a > 0) && (b > 0)) {
            System.out.print("Hello, what's your name? ");
        }
        String name;
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        name = kb.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Would you like to order some coffee, " + name + "? (y/n)");
        char yn;
        yn = sc.next().CharAt(0);

    }

}
```

Comment: Please post your all code.

Comment: Error is clear. Have you really declared `scanner`?

Comment: Hey andi, welcome to SO. Please read up on [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit yours accordingly. As is, it will most likely be downvoted to oblivion.

Comment: A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will help.

Comment: @mustafacil, not if that exceeds, say, 50 lines, please.

Comment: Sorry for everyone , I really need to read the rules firstly.

Comment: Please do read those, then edit your question. Remove the image, properly format the code, explain what you are trying to achieve, what doesn't work and - most importantly - state a clear and specific question. Then we'll be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

In the code you have posted in the edit, there are two small problems. Both are in this line:

```
    yn = sc.next().CharAt(0);
```

`sc` will not work since you have declared your `Scanner` variable with the name `kb` four lines higher up. And you have inadvertently typed a capital `C` in `CharAt`. Java is case sensitive, and this method follows the convention of method names beginning with a lowercase letter. The corrected version of the line reads:

```
    yn = kb.next().charAt(0);
```

With this correction I can run your program (as long as I remember to provide two integers in the command line).

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to initialise scanner variable; so add this line before using scanner;

```
Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
```